# Is this inference valid?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is the following inference valid provided that the variable $z$ does not occur free in $\Gamma$ (Note: No restriction regarding whether or not $z$ occurs free in $\phi$ is assumed) ?
$${
\Gamma \vdash \phi
\over
\Gamma \vdash \forall z.\phi
}$$

Comment: Yes, it is valid.

Comment: If we were to reverse the direction of the stated inference **and** add the provision that the _domain of discourse_ is non-empty, would the resultant inference be valid?  That is, is the following inference valid provided that the variable $z$ does not occur free in $\Gamma$ and the _domain of discourse_ is non-empty: $${
\Gamma \vdash \forall z.\phi
\over
\Gamma \vdash \phi
}$$

Comment: In this case, the rule is valid also without the restriction on $z$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the stated inference, when reversed in direction, doesn't require that $z$ not be free in $\Gamma$ (In my rush to post the follow-up comment/question, I forgot to incorporate the fact that in the upper level of the reversed inference, any $z$ in $\phi$ is bound and therefore unaffected by any $z$ in $\Gamma$ ... Oops! ... Thanks for the rescue!).

Comment: @Mauro, Based on your commentary here, I've only just now asked a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210417/unable-to-prove-this-simple-inference-using-sequent-calculus) related to this one ... I'd definitely be interested in your thoughts on this related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210417/unable-to-prove-this-simple-inference-using-sequent-calculus).  Thank for all of your assistance, so far!