# Unable to prove this simple inference using sequent calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In a recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209421/is-this-inference-valid), I asked if the folowing inference is valid provided that the variable $z$ does not occur free in $\Gamma$ (Note: No restriction regarding whether or not $z$ occurs free in $\phi$ is assumed) :

$${
\Gamma \vdash \phi
\over
\Gamma \vdash \forall z.\phi
}$$

One respondent, of high repute ($\simeq$ 25k), commented that it is.

Although, intuitively this inference seems valid, I have been unable to derive it proceeding from the rules of inference commonly given for sequent calculus (predicate logic version).

Assuming that all of the commonly given accounts of sequent calculus are sound and **complete**, shouldn't I be able to prove **any** valid formula/inference from their axiom(s) and rule(s) of inference?

Can any one offer a proof of the abovementioned inference that proceeds from the axiom(s) and rule(s) of inference of a sequent calculus?

Comment: I think that part of the misunderstanding is in the use of the "eigenvariable" in the rule. In your "form", of course we cannot impose the restriction $z$ not free in $\Gamma$ **and** $\phi$, because in this case the quantification on $z$ is quite useless. In this case, we impose  that $z$ is not free in $\Gamma$. The "purist" formulation (see Takeuti) separates symbols for free and bound variables; in this case we start with $\phi(y)$ and move to $\forall z \phi(z)$. Now the restriction is that the variable in the scope of the quantifier (i.e. $z$) must not be free in $\Gamma$ nor in $\phi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in :

- Gaisi Takeuti, [Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=Idl6K-W69NYC&pg=PA10) (2nd ed - 1987), page 10, the *quantifiers rules* for *sequent calculus* :

> $${
> \Gamma \to \Delta, \ F(y)
> \over
> \Gamma \to \Delta, \ \forall xF(x)
> } (\forall \text {-right})$$
>
> where $y$ does not occur in the lower sequent.

Being one of the "primitive" rule of the *sequent calculus*, it is enough to consider $\Delta = \emptyset$ in the $(\forall$-right) rule and we have the requested inference.

In this case, the restriction on $y$ not free in the lower sequent, amounts to $y$ not free in $\Gamma$ nor in $F$.

---

The rule corresponds to the $\forall$-introduction rule of *natural deduction* :

> $${
> A(y/x)
> \over
> \forall xA
> } (\forall \text {I})$$
>
> The rule of universal introduction has the variable restriction that $y$ must not occur free in any assumption that $A(y/x)$ depends on nor in $\forall xA$. [...] The variable restriction guarantees that $y$ stands for an "arbitrary individual" for which $A$ holds, which is the direct ground for asserting the universal proposition.

See : Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, [Structural Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZvACGkn9138C&pg=PA64) (2001), page 64.

---

Both *proof systems* need the restriction on the so-called *eigenvariable* $x$ of the rule, in order to avoid proving invalid formulae.

Consider the following counter-example, assuming $\Gamma = \{ x = 0 \}$ and $\Delta = \emptyset$.

Clearly :

> $x=0 \vdash x=0$

and thus, if we disregard the restriction, we can conclude with :

> $x=0 \vdash \forall x(x=0)$.

But both *natural deduction* and *sequent calculus* have no restrictions on the "deduction theorem" (i.e. the rules $\to$-introduction and $\Rightarrow$-right, respectively) and thus, from the above deduction, we can infer the invalid :

> > $\vdash (x=0) \to \forall x(x=0)$.

---

---

In :

- Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus & Jörg Flum & Wolfgang Thomas, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA59) (2nd ed 1994)

there is a "weird way" to present *sequent calculus*. The quantifier $\forall$ is *primitive* in the syntax [see page 16] but the rules of the calculus regarding it are all "derived".

In order to do this, we have to supplement the calculus with the "usual" equivalence between $\forall$ and $\lnot \exists \lnot$.

If so, we have the following derivation :

0) $\Gamma \ \ \varphi$ --- premise

1) $\Gamma \ \ \alpha \ \ \varphi$ --- for some $\alpha \in \Gamma$

2) $\Gamma \ \ \lnot \varphi \ \ \lnot \alpha$ --- (**Cp**) [*contraposition*, page 64]

3) $\Gamma \ \ \exists x \lnot \varphi \ \ \lnot \alpha$ --- **5.1(b)** [page 68 : here we need the restriction on $x$ not *free* in $\Gamma, \alpha$

4) $\Gamma \ \ \lnot \lnot \alpha \ \ \lnot \exists x \lnot \varphi$ --- (**Cp**)

5) $\Gamma \ \ \alpha \ \ \lnot \exists x \lnot \varphi$ --- **3.6(a1)** [page 65 : *double negation*]

6) $\Gamma \ \ \lnot \exists x \lnot \varphi$ --- $\alpha \in \Gamma$

> 7) $\Gamma \ \ \forall x \varphi$ --- from 6) by *equivalence* of $\lnot \exists \lnot$ and $\forall$ : $x$ not *free* in $\Gamma$.

---

You can compare with :

- Wolfgang Rautenberg, [A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=vMwixYpQTocC) (3rd ed - 2010),

that has a similar "austere" presentation of sequent calculus.

$\forall$ is primitive and the rules for quantifiers [page 92; see also page 79] are : $\forall$-elimination ($\forall1$) and $\forall$-introduction :

> $${
> X \vdash \alpha^y_x
> \over
> X \vdash \forall x \alpha
> } \ (\forall 2)$$
>
> with $y \notin \text {free} X \cup \text {var} \alpha$.

The rules for $\exists$ are derivable [see **Exercise 1**, page 97].

In this case, it is explicitly said [page 56] that :

> > Other logical symbols serve throughout merely as abbreviations, namely $∃x \alpha := ¬∀x¬ \alpha$, [...].

*Note* : the symbol $\varphi^y_x$ stands for [see page 59] the formula that results from replacing all free occurrences of $x$ in $\varphi$ by $y$.

Comment: Let $\mathscr{I}$ denote the inference stated in my original question.  I feel $\mathscr{I}$ is of a nature that is not readily amenable to the inference rule $(\forall \text {-right})$ you gave.  

With regard to $\mathscr{I}$, let $\Gamma \equiv \{ x = 0 \}$ and $\phi \equiv (x = 0)$.  

Then, since $\{ x = 0 \} \vdash (x = 0)$ is valid, we see that $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ is valid.  

Also, since $\{ x = 0 \} \vdash \forall z.(x = 0)$ is valid, we see that $\Gamma \vdash \forall z.\phi$ is valid.

Thus, $\mathscr{I}$ holds **even though** $x$ occurs free in $\Gamma$.

Comment: Also, whilst I agree with the $\forall$-introduction rule of natural deduction that you gave, it too addresses a situation that is very different to the original inference stated in my question.  The original inference stated in my question is 'quite happy' for the eigenvariable (or any other variable) of the  upper sequent's consequent to occur free in $\Gamma$.  Can you see that the original inference stated in my question is of a nature not readily amenable to the inference rule $(\forall \text {I})$ that you gave?

Comment: Just to clarify ... The inference stated in my original question makes no assumptions about (i.e. places no restrictions on) the relationship between the occurrences of variables in $\phi$ (free or bound) and the occurrences of variables in $\Gamma$ (free or bound).  The **only** restriction assumed by the inference stated in my original question, is that the quantifier variable $z$ in the lower sequent's consequent does not occur free in $\Gamma$.

Comment: The inference stated in my original question does **not** assert that $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi$ can be inferred from $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ irrespective of x being free in $\Gamma$ or not.  The inference stated in my original question **explicitly restricts** the quantifier variable of the lower sequent's consequent to being one that does **not** occur free in $\Gamma$.

Comment: The inference I stated in my original question does not come from a textbook.  It just seemed intuitively obvious to me, and I've not been able to think of a counter example to it.  That's why I previously posed a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209421/is-this-inference-valid) asking if it is a valid inference.  You (Mauro) stated that it is a valid inference.  On that basis, I set out to try and prove it using typical LK-type inference rules listed on Wikipedia and other sites that I google'd (there's plenty of them).

Comment: Mauro, do you still think that the inference I stated in my original question is valid?  If not, can you think of a counter example to it?  If you still are of the opinion that it is valid, then my challenge to you (and anyone, for that matter) is to prove it using whatever set of 'sequent calculus' type axioms and inference rules that you feel appropriate (within reason ... the set of axioms and inference rules that you choose would have to be considered plausible by the mainstream logic community, for example!).

Comment: @memexor The inference rule in the original question is exactly the rule $\forall$R from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Inference_rules (with $\Delta = \emptyset$ and $y=x$)
So there is nothing to prove

Comment: @Sebastian, That's one of the very first things that I tried, but the trouble is that the restriction given for the $\forall$R rule requires that $y$ must not appear anywhere in the lower sequent (which means that it cannot occur in $A$ ... using the notation for the $\forall$R rule in the Wikipedia article you cite), which in turn would require that the universal quantifier variable in the consequent of the lower sequent not appear in $A$ (or $\phi$ in my notation), **whereas** the inference rule stated in my original question does not restrict the universal quantifier variable in this way.

Comment: @Sebastian, In the previous comment I made, the requirement implicitly referred to by the words "which in turn would require that" is only a requirement within the context of your proposed solution (wherein, $y = x$) ... that's the problem!

Comment: @memexor The Wikipedia article actually gives to alternative restrictions on the $\forall$R rule:
1) "the variable $y$ must not occur free within $\Gamma$"
in this case just take $\Delta = \emptyset$ and $y=x$

2) "Alternatively, the variable $y$ must not appear anywhere in the respective lower sequent"
in this case just take $\Delta = \emptyset$ and $y$ any variable not used in $\Gamma$ and $\phi$ (this is always possible because $\Gamma$ has finite length)

Comment: @Sebastian, The trouble is, in the second case that you mention (i.e. wherein you take $y$ to be a variable that does not occur in $\Gamma$ or $\phi$), all you do is end up proving:
$${
\Gamma \vdash \phi
\over
\Gamma \vdash \forall z.\phi
}$$  
**where** $z$ does not occur in $\Gamma$ **or** $\phi$.  
In contrast, the inference rule stated in my original question permits $z$ to occur (free or bound) within $\phi$.  For example, ...  
$\Gamma = \{ x \neq 0 \}$ and  
$\phi = ((x^2 > 0) \land (z = z))$  
is permitted.

Comment: @Sebastian, By the way, in the Wikipedia article that you cite, for the $\forall$R rule given therein, the restriction that they stipulate for it that reads "the variable $y$ must not occur free within $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$" is insufficiently strong ... it should have additionally stipulated that $y$ must not occur free within $A$ ... and that, of course, rules out your proposed solution because the inference rule stated in my original question does not permit one to assume that $z$ does not occur free in $\phi$ (see the example that I gave in my previous comment).

Comment: no. its ok for y to be free in A

Comment: @Sebastian, $y$ can't be free in $A$ in the $\forall$R rule that we've been discussing.  For example, consider $A \equiv (x = y)$ and $\Delta = \emptyset$.  If the rule permitted $y$ to occur free in $A$, it would mean that we could infer $\Gamma \vdash \forall x.(x = y)$, which we clearly cannot!

Comment: @memexor You are right. Sorry. 
The rule is definitly correct. It's given in [Ebbinghaus' Book](https://books.google.de/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q&f=false) But he uses diffrent sequent rules. (see 5.5 b4)

Comment: @memexor The restriction to the $\forall$R rule should be y **not free** in the lower sequence. This gives a correct and complete proof calculus. And then you can indeed take $y=x$ and $\Delta = \emptyset$ to get your result. Maybe the more restrictive rule that y should not at all occur in the lower sequence doesn't give a complete calculus, I don't know.

Comment: Mauro and @Sebastian, I've got some pressing work deadlines that I have to meet, but at the earliest opportunity that I get to squirrel away some time to further analyse this overall logic topic with you guys, I will.  I'm very grateful for your inputs so far, and I'll definitely be adding further to this topic as soon as I can.

Comment: @Sebastian, When I first tried to prove the inference stated in my original question, the problem that I came up against was that I couldn't choose $y$ = $x$ in the Wikipedia $\forall$R rule because of the accompanying restriction which stated that the variable y must not appear **anywhere** in the lower sequent. I wondered whether that restriction was mistaken for a couple of reasons: (i) For inference rules, restrictions placed on variables usually mention the word 'free'; and ... _continued_

Comment: @Sebastian _Continuation_ ... (ii) The first of Wikipedia's two alternative accounts of the restriction applicable to the $\forall$R rule specified a level of restriction that was insufficiently restrictive, and so I wondered whether the level of restriction stipulated by the second of the two accounts might have also been problematic/mistaken (my hope was that it may have been unnecessarily restrictive).  I immediately looked through my bookmarked 'logic' articles (an extensive list), and the restriction specified for the $\forall$R rule always fell in one of two categories: ... _continued_

Comment: @Sebastian _Continuation_ ... (1) $y$ cannot occur free in $\Gamma$, $\Delta$ or $A$; (2) $y$ must not occur in the lower sequent.  So, my suspicion/hope that there existed a less restrictive (but accurate nonetheless) restriction on the $\forall$R rule that would permit me to choose $y$ = $x$, remained just that, a suspicion/hope.  I suppose I could always search to see if there's a book/paper that mentions such a less restrictive restriction for the $\forall$R rule ... If time permits, I will.

Comment: @memexor (1) and (2) are both to restrective. The correct restriction should be y cannot occur free in $\Gamma, \Delta$ and $\exists x A$. That is: y cannot occur free in the lower sequent. At least this gives a correct and complete calculus and the statement in the OP is easy to prove.(because this permits you to let y=x)

Comment: @memexor this is also how Ebbinghaus gives the rule in his book linked above (he gives it for $\exists$L)

Comment: @Sebastian, I just noticed that Mauro was able to find such a [book excerpt](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZvACGkn9138C&pg=PA64) (specifically, p.64 of Structural Proof Theory (2001) by Sara Negri & Jan von Plato).  The restriction stated there for the rule of **universal** introduction permits us to choose $y$ = $x$.  Yay!

Comment: @memexor That's what I said ;)

Comment: @Sebastian, Indeed, but the advantage of the 'Sara Negri & Jan von Plato' book excerpt stated above versus the Ebbinghaus account, is that it's more direct (it refers to the **universal quantifier** directly rather than indirectly through the existential quantifier).  By the way, I am curious, how did you manage to find the inference stated in my original question within the Ebbinghaus book (5.5 b4)? ... Until I saw it stated there, I was starting to question my belief that it was correct!

Comment: @memexor I have a copy of that book and used to work with it,so I remembered there were some exercises on derived sequent rules. I just looked it up and was lucky :)

Comment: Mauro and @Sebastian ... I'd like to reward you **both** for your high quality inputs to the analysis of this topic.  One way, that comes to mind, is for Sebastian to answer the [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209421/is-this-inference-valid) by citing the presence of the concerned inference in the Ebbinghaus book (5.5 b4) ... That would ensure that readers **know** that it's a correct inference, and I could then accept Sebastian's answer there, whilst accepting Mauro's answer here (end result ... both of you are rewarded for your efforts). Does that seem reasonable?